# Determine if $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x} \ dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, improper-integrals

> Determine if $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x} \ dx$ converges.

When $x$ gets close to $0$ $e^{\sqrt{x}} \ge 0$ so $-\frac1x \le\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x}$ and since $\lim_{t \to 0} -\int_{t}^{1} \frac1x  \ dx = -(\ln(1)-\ln(t)) =  \ln(t) \to \infty $ the integral diverges. Is the reasoning here correct? I'm not sure I can make the approximation $-\frac1x \le\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}{x}$ when $x$ is near $0$?

Comment: You can use the fact that $e^{\sqrt x }  \le 1 + \sqrt x  + x$ for all $0\leq x \leq 1$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3726469

Comment: Your reasoning does not work since $\log(t)$ tends to *minus* infinity. Saying that your integral is at least minus infinity does not tell you much.

Answer (score 3):

You have$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}x}{\frac1{\sqrt x}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}{\sqrt x}=1.$$So, since the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}$ converges, then so does your integral.

Your approach is wrong, because you compared your function with a negative function.

Comment: How did you get the approximation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \le \frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}x$?

Comment: I didn't get that approximation. All I proved was that the limit of the quotient of $\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}x$ with $\frac1{\sqrt x}$ exists in $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: But where did the fraction $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ came from in the first case?

Comment: From the fact that $\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}x=\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}{\sqrt x}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt x}$, together with the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sqrt x}-1}{\sqrt x}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the Taylor approximation of the exponential function, you know that
$$
{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1\over x}={1\over\sqrt{x}}+{1\over 2}+O(x^{1/2}),\quad x\to 0+.
$$
It follows that there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
0\le {e^{\sqrt{x}}-1\over x}\le {1\over\sqrt{x}}+C, \quad 0<x\le 1,
$$
This bound and the fact that the integral of $x^{-1/2}$ over $(0,1)$ converges are enough to answer your question.